# How do I update Datagridview in the MainForm when a customer is added in the Create Customer Form?

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I am trying to show data in a datagridview in MainForm. I am adding customers in the Create Customer Form.

```cs
private void createButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string timestamp = Info.createTimestamp();
    string userName = Info.getCurrentUserName();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(countryTxtBx.Text) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(cityTxtBx.Text) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(addressTxtBx.Text) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(cityTxtBx.Text) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(zipTxtBx.Text) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(phoneTxtBx.Text) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameTxtBx.Text) ||
        (yesButton.Checked == false && noButton.Checked == false))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter all fields");
    }
    else
    {
        int countryId = Info.createRecord(timestamp, userName, "country", $"'{countryTxtBx.Text}'");
        int cityId = Info.createRecord(timestamp, userName, "city", $"'{cityTxtBx.Text}', '{countryId}'");
        int addressId = Info.createRecord(timestamp, userName, "address", $"'{addressTxtBx.Text}', '', '{cityId}', '{zipTxtBx.Text}', '{phoneTxtBx.Text}'");
        Info.createRecord(timestamp, userName, "customer", $"'{nameTxtBx.Text}', '{addressId}', '{(yesButton.Checked ? 1 : 0)}'");
        Close();
    }
}
```

I am able to pull the data from the MySql but when I add or delete a customer the datagridview in the MainForm doesn't update. Is there a way to update the datagridview in the Main Form when I add customers in the Create Customer Form?

```cs
public void DataFill()
{
    // Open connection
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(Info.conString);
    conn.Open();

    // Create new DataAdapter
    string query = $"SELECT * FROM customer";
    MySqlDataAdapter SDA = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SDA.Fill(dt);
    // Render data onto the screen
    customerDGV.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Comment: Well, you could just call DataFill after the Create Customer form is closed? A couple of other things: 1) by the look of your `Info` class methods, you're creating SQL manually. Don't do that - use parameterized queries, or else your app is vulnerable to SQL injection and 2) you need to close (or better, dispose of) the connection and adapter objects you create in `DataFill`.

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the MainForm's DataGridView everytime you add or delete a customer. Heres a way to achieve that...

```
//event to open the create customer form
private void OpenCreateCustomerForm(){
//first, create an instance of the form
frmCreateCustomer frm = new frmCreateCustomer();
/*second, add the function DataFill() to the FormClosed event of the create customer form, so everytime you close it, the MainForms datagridview will get updated*/
frm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler((object s, FormClosedEventArgs f) => { DataFill();});
//finally, show the create customer form
frm.ShowDialog();
};
```

Comment: I tried that but still doesn't refresh the MainForm's DataGridView. I have to close the MainForm and reopen it in order to refresh the DataGridView

Comment: using (var newFrm = new Form2())
{
    newFrm.ShowDialog();  // execution of Form1 stops until Form2 is closed
}

// read the file and update the DataGridView (this line executes when Form2 is closed)